# Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 RC Cordova Android Build Exit Code 1

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 RC to develop a Cordova app.  The app was working fine and being tested on my Samsung Galaxy S6 device fine for about two days.  One day, after a lunch break, I came back to my app and started receiving an error when I tried to deploy to either an emulator or a device that read

```
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

After about two days of researching this issue, I have yet to find a fix.  I cannot test my app except in the "Ripple" environment, which is not useful for testing this app.

Here is the relevant output:

```
1>  -code-gen:
1>  [mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
1>  [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
1>  [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
1>       [echo] Handling aidl files...
1>       [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
1>       [echo] ----------
1>       [echo] Handling Resources...
1>       [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
1>       [aapt] D:\Stack Solutions\StackTFSSolutions\NRCA Phone App\AppRoot\platforms\android\ant-build\AndroidManifest.xml:6: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenOrientation' with value 'Portrait').
1>       [aapt]
1>  Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c ""D:\Stack Solutions\StackTFSSolutions\NRCA Phone App\AppRoot\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug --ant "
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I believe this error occurs because the app is already on the device.  I've used ADB to uninstall and reinstall and that seems to get things working again.  

Make sure you have the device connected. Open ```C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\``` folder in command prompt. Then type `adb uninstall ` + `name-of-you-apk.apk`.  Also, you can try installing the apk with `adb install` and if that installs the apk, try installing with VS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spent 3 hours on this one after migrating to vs 2015 from 2013.

The solution came when I changed **Tools>>Options>>Projects and Solutions>>Build and Run (build output and build log) verbosity to Diagnostic**. Which gave me more information as to why it was not building.

I discovered in my case a **cordova-plugin-file transfer** was causing it, so I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and viola it works!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Nodejs and install node (Version 0.10.28)

[Nodejs 0.10.28 Installation source](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v0.10.28/)

Worked for me